# c++ can't pass an argument with CreateProcess

Tags: c++, winapi, createprocess

i have to pass a string into my process, but for some reason i can't

i've tried to pass a path and an argument in function, i've tried to put a \0 after the argument, i've tried to pass an argument or space + an argument but it doesn't passes.
could you please help me?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
void _tmain(int argc, TCHAR* argv[])
{
    cout << "we are here!\n";
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;


    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

    string first = "C:\\Users\\User\\source\\repos\\1\\x64\\Debug\\1.exe";  //Initializing a name of our file
    wstring temp = wstring(first.begin(), first.end());  // Initializing an object of wstring
    LPCWSTR file_name = temp.c_str();  // Applying c_str() method on temp

    string s1 = " 1.exe 1\0";
    LPWSTR cl1 = (LPWSTR)s1.c_str();

    // Start the child process. 
    if (!CreateProcess(file_name,   // No module name (use command line)
        cl1,        // Command line
        NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
        NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
        FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
        CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,              // Creating console for our application
        NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
        NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 
        &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
        &pi)           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
        )
    {
        printf("CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError());
        return;
    }

    // Wait until child process exits.
    WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
    // Close process and thread handles. 
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
       

    cout << "we are done!\n";
}
```

thanks for your help in advance

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don’t think casting a c_str to LPWSTR makes it so.

Comment: You haven't said what's actually going wrong, but this is UB: `LPWSTR cl1 = (LPWSTR)s1.c_str();`.  Instead, from C++17 on, you can do: `LPWSTR cl1 = s1.data();`

Comment: Also, please don't tag C++ questions as C.  Removed.

Comment: @PaulSanders good point but it is a wide string so `std::wstring` should be used, this is another reason to avoid c-style casting

Comment: @thedemons Good point.  Removing the cast will trap this ofc, and that parameter needs to be non-const for reasons buried in the past.

Comment: Every cast is a lie. It's up to the developer to make sure that that lie is inconsequential. `(LPWSTR)s1.c_str()` isn't.

Comment: `wstring(first.begin(), first.end())` is not the correct way to convert a `std::string` to a `std::wstring`. That merely upscales each `char` as-is to a `wchar_t`. Instead, you need an actual data conversion from 8bit/ANSI to UTF-16 , such as with `MultiByteToWideChar()`, `std::wstring_convert`, ICU/ICONV, etc. That said, in this particular code, just use `std::wstring` exclusively, with wide string literals prefixed with  `L`, eg: `wstring first = L"C:\\... "; LPCWSTR file_name = first.c_str();`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Note that std::wstring_convert uses codecvt which is deprecated in C++17, `MultiByteToWideChar` is recommended but it's windows only.

Comment: @thedemons deprecated, but still works. In any case, this code is Windows-only to begin with, so no point worrying about using Win32 APIs for string handling

Comment: @RemyLebeau Actually I've heard that codecvt implementation is chaos in some cppcon talk, but couldn't remember why it is "chaos", but that was the reason it got deprecated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you compiling in Unicode or Multibyte (MBCS)?

Assuming you are compiling in Unicode you can avoid the use of string objects and use wstring objects instead.

To initialize a wstring you have to prefix the double quoted string with an L, i.e.

```
wstring first(L"C:\\Users\\User\\source\\repos\\1\\x64\\Debug\\1.exe");
```

So, you can avoid the use of **temp** variable.

***Note**: Is more efficient to initialize a (w)string using the constructor instead of the assignment operator.*

Also, the cast in

```
string s1 = " 1.exe 1\0";
LPWSTR cl1 = (LPWSTR)s1.c_str();
```

is nos valid, as **s1.c_str()** return type is **const char*** (or **LPCSTR**).

Instead, you can declare

```
wstring s1(L" 1.exe 1\0");
LPCWSTR cl1 = s1.c_str();
```

In fact, you don't need to assign the result of c_str() to another variable. You can call to c_str() when you are calling to CreateProcess. The code could be something as:

```
//Initializing a name of our file
wstring first(L"C:\\Users\\User\\source\\repos\\1\\x64\\Debug\\1.exe");  
wstring s1(L" 1.exe 1\0");

// Start the child process. 
if (!CreateProcess(first.c_str(),   // No module name (use command line)
    const_cast<LPWSTR>(s1.c_str()),        // Command line
    NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
    NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
    FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
    CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,              // Creating console for our application
    NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
    NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 
    &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
    &pi)           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
    )
{
    printf("CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError());
    return;
}
```

If you are compiling with MBCS you should change wstring by string and remove the L prefix when initializing strings. The rest of the code could remain the same.

Comment: *more efficient to initialize a (w)string using the constructor instead of the assignment operator*. Note on this: the copy operation will be optimized away by the compiler, it actually invokes the constructor, not the copy assignment.

Comment: "*Are you compiling in Unicode or Multibyte*" - it is clear from the code that Unicode is the case, by virtue of `CreateProcess()` taking Unicode strings. "*Is more efficient to initialize a (w)string using the constructor instead of the assignment operator*" - `wstring first = L"....";` uses the constructor, not the assignment operator.

Comment: That won't compile. The API expects an `LPTSTR` (non-`const`) as its second argument. `c_str()` won't produce that. `data()` might, assuming C++17 (or later).

Comment: If you *must* `const_cast` (which you don't) at least use the correct target type (that's `LPTSTR`, not `LPWSTR`). Or, if you're brave, subscribe to a character encoding, and call `CreateProcessW` instead of the generic-text mapping `CreateProcess`.